# boost::lockfree::spsc_queue allocator maximum size?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, boost, fifo

I need to buffer a bunch of incoming 10GigE data so that I can write it to disk later.  Doing so sequentially is an issue since the device that I am reading from will overflow if I don't service it quickly enough.

In search of a solution, I stumbled across boost::lockfree::spsc_queue.  In particular, I like the fact that I can pre-allocate the memory for the queue, since resizing during a push() could potentially cause a slowdown that could lead to an overflow.

However, given the data rate, I need a LARGE buffer.  As a result, I'm wondering what is the maximum size that I can allocate for the queue (in both # of items and in terms of bytes).  The system that I am planning on deploying on has 24GB available, so I was hoping to allocate as much as 16GB to ensure that the queue never fills up.  A final note is that the code will reside on a Linux machine (x86-64 architecture), so if there's any required kernel parameters to alter this size, that would be good to know as well.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with the queue, I was able to allocate (dynamically) a huge queue.  There appears to be no limit.

Statically though, you are limited and I was receiving errors when I was creating large, statically allocated buffers.  I didn't play around with it enough to find the exact value though.